# How to replace a string depending on the parent ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm testing a bunch of content and rather than deal with multiple pages, I'm just loading each element with PHP from one index page. Each "page" has a section of code with a breadcrumbs line. I'm trying to use JavaScript to target the "current" location line and replace it with the ID of its parent to show the current location.

Here's what I've already tried: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/7ktughab/24/)

```
$('.show #filter.menu').each(function() {

  var parID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
  var parCL = $(this).parent().attr('class');

  if (parCL.search('show'))
    $('.menu .breadcrumbs .current').text($(this).text().replace('Here', parID));

});
```

Ideally I want "Here" to be replaced with the contents of the ID of the breadcrumb's parent. Such as: **Home | Archives** or **Home | People**.

But instead I'm getting **Home | Home Archives**.

I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `#filter.menu` should never be repeated.  Ids are expected to be unique by web standards.

Comment: it's not doing any harm in this example. It will eventually be unique.

Comment: @JeffSydor um, yes it does harm when it is impossible to select them all and loop over them.

Comment: then why does it work here? https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/7ktughab/26/

Comment: It works because most browser engines are very tolerant of violations of the standard. However, it would be correct to assign the class "filter" to the sections instead of the id "filter", because according to the standard an id can only exist once.

Comment: You should always be doing your best to code to web standards, because those are the standards by which browsers are suppossed to be developing their html implementations to, and if you do not do so, s*** can happen.  Case in point, when you give multiple things the same ID and then use getElementById and wonder..... why is it only returning just one?

Comment: Yeah, no kidding. But as I ALREADY stated, it will eventually be unique and a non-issue. This is just for the purposes of developing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lays in this line:

```
$('.menu .breadcrumbs .current').text($(this).text().replace('Here', parID));
```

In the context, `$(this)` refers to the current element of the loop from the first line. So `$(this).text()` returns "Home Here" because both words are in the same section width the id "filter". Then your code replaces "Here" width the parent id. So the result is "Home archives".

So instead of replacing "Here" you could just set the text of `.current` to the parent ID:

```
$('.menu .breadcrumbs .current').text(parID);
```

Comment: Wow thanks! That's what happens when trying to mix explanations from several sources!